# What is the RPC Control Windows Object Manager namespace?

Tags: windows, ntfs, internals

I am working on a presentation about symbolic link exploitation on Windows. Most attacks will make use of NTFS junctions with symbolic links created under the RPC Control object namespace. Could someone explain to me what this namespace is and what happens when an RPC Control symbolic link, inside an NTFS junction, that points to a file on disk is read by a process?

Comment: how you can say that *..created under the RPC Control object namespace* , if you even dont know what is this ? may be this *\RPC Control* directory in nt object namespace

Comment: I mean I've used it blindly in the past without actually knowing why that namespace exists in the first place. I mean what is its original purpose?

Comment: simply exist directory *\RPC Control*